# How to you create a decorator pattern in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, proxy, decorator

I'm trying to create objects from a set of classes without having to define each set... essentially I'm trying to create the decorator pattern. In typescript this seems to be near impossible due to compiling restrictions.

I've tried using Proxies. No dice.

Here's the usage I'm trying to accomplish (some code is missing to allow what I'm trying to do - which is what I'm trying to solve).

```
class Person {

    public name:string;
    public age:number;

    public identify(){
        console.log(`${this.name} age ${this.age}`);
    }


}

class Child {

    public Mother:Person;
    public Father:Person;

    public logParents(){
        console.log("Parents:");
        this.Mother.identify();
        this.Father.identify();
    }

}

class Student {

    public school:string;

    public logSchool(){
        console.log(this.school);
    }

}

let Dad = new Person();
Dad.name = "Brad";
Dad.age = 32;

let Mom = new Person();
Mom = new Student(Mom);
Mom.name = "Janet";
Mom.age = 34;
Mom.school = "College of Night School Moms";

let Johnny = new Person();
Johnny = new Child(Johnny);
Johnny = new Student(Johnny);
Johnny.name = "Johnny";
Johnny.age = 12;
Johnny.Mother = Mom;
Johnny,Father = Dad;
Johnny.school = "School for kids who can't read good";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [java example here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Java) as the base, I changed it a bit to fit your code:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    identify(): void;
}

class SimplePerson implements Person {
    public name: string;
    public age: number;

    public identify(){
        console.log(`${this.name} age ${this.age}`);
    }
}

abstract class PersonDecorator implements Person {
    protected decoratedPerson: Person;

    public constructor(person: Person) {
        this.decoratedPerson = person;
    }

    public get name() {
        return this.decoratedPerson.name;
    }

    public get age() {
        return this.decoratedPerson.age;
    }

    identify(): void {
        return this.decoratedPerson.identify();
    }
}

class Child extends PersonDecorator {
    public Mother: Person;
    public Father: Person;

    public logParents(){
        console.log("Parents:");
        this.Mother.identify();
        this.Father.identify();
    }
}

class Student extends PersonDecorator {
    public school:string;

    public logSchool(){
        console.log(this.school);
    }
}

let Dad = new SimplePerson();
Dad.name = "Brad";
Dad.age = 32;

let Mom = new SimplePerson();
Mom = new Student(Mom);
Mom.name = "Janet";
Mom.age = 34;
(Mom as Student).school = "College of Night School Moms";

let Johnny = new SimplePerson();
Johnny = new Child(Johnny);
Johnny = new Student(Johnny);
Johnny.name = "Johnny";
Johnny.age = 12;
(Johnny as Child).Mother = Mom;
(Johnny as Child).Father = Dad;
(Johnny as Student).school = "School for kids who can't read good";
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Person%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20identify()%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20SimplePerson%20implements%20Person%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20age%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20identify()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60%24%7Bthis.name%7D%20age%20%24%7Bthis.age%7D%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aabstract%20class%20PersonDecorator%20implements%20Person%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20decoratedPerson%3A%20Person%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor(person%3A%20Person)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.decoratedPerson%20%3D%20person%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20name()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.decoratedPerson.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20age()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.decoratedPerson.age%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20identify()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.decoratedPerson.identify()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20PersonDecorator%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Mother%3A%20Person%3B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Father%3A%20Person%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20logParents()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Parents%3A%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Mother.identify()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Father.identify()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Student%20extends%20PersonDecorator%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20school%3Astring%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20logSchool()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.school)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20Dad%20%3D%20new%20SimplePerson()%3B%0ADad.name%20%3D%20%22Brad%22%3B%0ADad.age%20%3D%2032%3B%0A%0Alet%20Mom%20%3D%20new%20SimplePerson()%3B%0AMom%20%3D%20new%20Student(Mom)%3B%0AMom.name%20%3D%20%22Janet%22%3B%0AMom.age%20%3D%2034%3B%0A(Mom%20as%20Student).school%20%3D%20%22College%20of%20Night%20School%20Moms%22%3B%0A%0Alet%20Johnny%20%3D%20new%20SimplePerson()%3B%0AJohnny%20%3D%20new%20Child(Johnny)%3B%0AJohnny%20%3D%20new%20Student(Johnny)%3B%0AJohnny.name%20%3D%20%22Johnny%22%3B%0AJohnny.age%20%3D%2012%3B%0A(Johnny%20as%20Child).Mother%20%3D%20Mom%3B%0A(Johnny%20as%20Child).Father%20%3D%20Dad%3B%0A(Johnny%20as%20Student).school%20%3D%20%22School%20for%20kids%20who%20can't%20read%20good%22%3B))

Comment: Right. I missed that, in the java example they have private methods and not public ones, and that's why it's not an issue. But this problem exists in java, and probably other OO languages. Basically you're looking for a decorator pattern with mixins. That's more than possible in typescript/javascript, with or without proxies, but I suspect that it might be a bit of an overkill, at least for most scenarios. What is your scenario? is your code just an example of your problem or is it your real model?

Comment: This is just a simplified example. The real scenario has many more... basically a base object with a series of 'extensions' that can be mixed and matched in any number of combinations.

Comment: How does that have 0 (now 1) up vote?  That is a great example and answer!!